# mouseout FadeOut trouble no JavaScript/jQuery applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

what could be the problem here? on the Products Tab when Hovering MouseOut? because i want
my mouseover menu to fadeout exactly when the transition of the text fadeouts too, please help, Thanks :) This is my Website for observing

cann.net78.net

by the way this is the code

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{font-family:HelveticaLTStd-Light;}
table{font-size:80%}
a{color:#f0f0f0;text-decoration:none;
-o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}
a:hover{color:#006600;}
font-family:HelveticaLTStd-Light;
td.menu{background:#DEB887}
table.menu
{
font-size:100%;
color:#f0f0f0;
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
background:#558800;
opacity:0.9;
}
body {
background:url(wall.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
}
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
position:relative;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showmenu(elmnt)
{
document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
}
function hidemenu(elmnt)
{
document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<br>
<br><table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <th align="left" width="430"><font color="cccccc" face="HelveticaLTStd-Light" size="15">C-Ann Trading</font><br>
    <font color="#f0f0f0" size="5">and Computer Services    </font> </th>
    <th width="120" style="border-right:1px solid #000000;border-color:#cccccc"><br><font size="3"><a href="index.html">Home</a></font></th>
    <th width="120" style="border-right:1px solid #000000;border-color:#cccccc"><br><font size="3"><a href="about.htm">About Us</a></font></th>
    <th width="120" onmouseover="showmenu('products')" onmouseout="hidemenu('products')" style="border-right:1px solid #000000;border-color:#cccccc"><br><font size="3" color="#f0f0f0">Products</font>
        <table border="1" class="menu" id="products" width="150">
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="notebook.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNotebooks</a></tr></th>
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="monitor.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspMonitors</a></tr></th>
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="component.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspComponents</a></tr></th>
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="software.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspSoftwares</a></tr></th>
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="peripheral.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPeripherals</a></tr></th>
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="network.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNetworking</a></tr></th>
        <tr><th align="left" class="menu"><a href="storage.htm">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspStorage Devices</a></tr></th>
```

Comment: Instead of linking to your website, include an excerpt of code specific to your issue.

You need to help us help you.

Comment: I agree with @crynix for the lack of good code...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly stop the use of `<table>` for doing such a dropdown menu. Make the use of nested `<ul><li>` markups, and give a pure css solution a shot.

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

If i may, and from what i see of the sourcecode of your website, maybe you should start over again from scratch with keeping in mind that html is a semantic markup language that helps (people and) bots to identify your content.

Try to think at your content as if you were writing a book, with a title, a summary, some paragraphs etc...

Make good use of that for a simple start : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp

You may find it more difficult at first sight, but you'll grow your skill and also you'll win some seo ranks which you may find useful.

Comment: but, i was asking about the code for menu fadeout time, not what about my web content?well, thanks for the css info.